# What is the equivalent of weight_filler from Caffe in Tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, caffe

I'm trying to convert a TensorFlow to Caffe model, but in Caffe what about `weight_filler`? My model in tf is:

```
model.add(Conv2D(16, kernel_size=(5, 5), padding="same", activation='selu', 
                 input_shape=(64, 64, 1)))

model.add(Conv2D(16, kernel_size=(5, 5), padding="same", activation='selu'))

model.add(Conv2D(16, kernel_size=(5, 5), padding="same", activation='selu'))

model.add(Conv2D(16, kernel_size=(5, 5), padding="same", activation='selu'))

model.add(Conv2D(16, kernel_size=(5, 5), padding="same", activation='selu'))

model.add(Conv2D(16, kernel_size=(5, 5), padding="same", activation='selu'))

model.add(Conv2D(16, kernel_size=(5, 5), padding="same", activation='selu'))

model.add(Conv2D(16, kernel_size=(5, 5), padding="same", activation='selu'))

model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2),strides=(2,2)))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`weight_filler` is the type of generator used to initialize weights and biases. In tensorflow if it's not specified the default initializer is `glorot_uniform_initializer` which is also called `Xavier uniform initializer` so the equivalent initializer in Caffe is `xavier`:

```
weight_filler {
  type: "xavier"
}
```